# Xcode Organizer Archiving is using too much RAM in macOS Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave

Using Xcode 10 and 11, when I try to Distribute App > iOS App Store in Xcode Organizer, it always use huge amount of application memory (as you can see from the "Force Quit Applications" prompt below, it used 18GB application memory) when the Xcode is "Fetching App Store Configuration".

To temporarily resolve this problem. I have to force quit the Xcode and restart my iMac (macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with 16GB RAM). After a fresh restart, the Xcode passed the "Fetching App Store Configuration" stage almost using no time.

Anyone knows why? and how to resolve?

[image: Force Quit Applications screenshot]